# Flag и связанная с ним активность

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины, тревоги

На SO есть понятие flag — это не только «тревога», но и просто сообщение о том, что данный вопрос/комментарий требует внимания модератора. (Например, для случая, когда нужно удалить свой комментарий, а прав нету.)

Связанные понятия: to flag, flagged message, go to first/next/selected flag.

Предлагаю использовать вместо слова «тревога» более нейтральное слово «сигнал». Тогда

- to flag = отправить сигнал, отсигнализировать?
- flagged message = ?
- go to first flag = «перейти к первому сигналу»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Выбранный ответ*.

- flag = тревога
- to flag = отметить тревогой
- (privilege to) flag messages = (право) отмечать сообщения тревогой
- first flag = первая тревога
- useful flag = полезная тревога
- flagged message = сообщение, отмеченное «тревогой»

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- Вариант 1

  - flag = жалоба
  - to flag = пожаловаться
  - (privilege to) flag messages = (право) жаловаться на сообщения
  - first flag = первая жалоба
  - useful flag = полезная жалоба
  - flagged message = сообщение с «жалобой»
- Вариант 2

  - flag = тревога
  - to flag = бить тревогу
  - (privilege to) flag messages = (право) отмечать сообщения
  - first flag = первый сигнал
  - useful flag = полезный сигнал
  - flagged message = отмеченное сообщение
- Вариант 3

  - flag = замечание
  - to flag = сделать замечание
  - (privilege to) flag messages = (право) делать замечание
  - first flag = первое сделанное замечание
  - useful flag = полезное замечание
  - flagged message = сообщение с замечанием
- Вариант 4

  - flag = тревога
  - to flag = пожаловаться
  - (privilege to) flag messages = (право) жаловаться на сообщения
  - first flag = первая жалоба
  - useful flag = полезная жалоба
  - flagged message = сообщение, отмеченное «тревогой»
- Вариант 5

  - flag = сигнал
  - to flag = отправить сигнал
  - (privilege to) flag messages = (право) патрулировать сообщения
  - first flag = первый сигнал
  - useful flag = полезный сигнал
  - flagged message = отмеченное сообщение
- Вариант 6

  - flag = жалоба
  - to flag = пожаловаться
  - (privelege to) flag messages = (возможность) отправлять жалобы на сообщения
  - first flag = первый сигнал тревоги
  - useful flag = полезный сигнал тревоги (вот тут не уверен)
  - flagged message = сообщение, на которое пожаловались
- Вариант 7

  - flag = пометка
  - to flag = пометить
  - (privelege to) flag messages = (возможность) помечать сообщения
  - first flag = первая пометка
  - useful flag = полезная пометка
  - flagged message = помеченное сообщение
- Вариант 8

  - flag = кляуза
  - to flag = накляузничать
  - (privilege to) flag messages = (право) кляузничать на сообщения
  - first flag = первая кляуза
  - useful flag = полезная кляуза
  - flagged message = сообщение под кляузой
- Вариант 9

  - flag = тревога
  - to flag = тревога
  - (privilege to) flag messages = (право) поднимать тревогу
  - first flag = первая тревога
  - useful flag = полезная тревога
  - flagged message = сообщение с тревогой

Comment: вариант 3 (про «замечание») — на мой взгляд, выглядит наиболее органично и «благозвучно». правда, затрудняюсь оценить ассоциативную связь со «школьными замечаниями».

Comment: Все таки, мне кажется, что мы даем рекомендации, а не замечания. В сообществе отношения `коллега <-> коллега`, а не `преподаватель <-> ученик`. Само действие "flag" обращено к сообществу, а не к автору, то есть, при переводе как "замечание", мы будем делать "замечание" сообществу на вопрос.

Comment: да, действительно, если получателем «замечания» является не «нарушитель», и, тем более, если он даже не оповещается о получении «замечания», то это уже явно не «замечание». и такой вариант названия не подходит к используемому механизму.